# Align image within a span to be to the right of a table cell

Tags: html, css

I made a JS Fiddle to show you what is currently happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/70z5Lm2r/2/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">

            </td>
            <td class="second">
                <span>
                    <span onClick={doSomething} class="underline-hover">
                        <img src="pic.png" />
                        This is some clickable data. Sometimes it overflows.
                    </span>

                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
    width: 40%;
}

.second {
    width: 60%;
}

.underline-hover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
}
```

As you can see, if you hover over the user icon, the underline affect happens on the text. This is because both the text and the image are within the `span` that has the `underline-hover` class and the `onClick` handler applied.

What I want to have happen is that when a hover happens on the text, only the text is highlighted. When a hover happens on the icon, nothing happens. However, I still want the icon to be flush to the right and the text to wrap accordingly as it currently is displayed.

What I have tried is taking the `img` tag out of the inner `span` like so:

```
<span>
    <span onClick={doSomething} class="underline-hover">
        This is some clickable data. Sometimes it overflows.
    </span>
    <img src="pic.png" />
</span>
```

This satisfies the behavior but the `float` property of the `img` tag causes it to be removed from the flow of the page, causing the text and icon to jumbled together.

Any help achieving the behavior and look that I want would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you use `display: flex;` on the parent `<span>`? You could then use `margin-left: auto` on the image. Additionally… use `<button>` for interactive elements (as suggested by your `onClick` attribute), not a `<span>`. It's bad practice, bad for accessibility, and it's a pain to add the native interactivity back into it…

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was very close. Because you're floating the `img` right, it needs to be before the `<span>`.

```
<span>
    <img src="pic.png" />
    <span onClick={doSomething} class="underline-hover">
        This is some clickable data. Sometimes it overflows.
    </span>
</span>
```

Next, make a style for `.underline-hover` with a `margin-right:20px;` Currently the span fills the width of it's container, so the img isn't triggering the hover, the span is. We create a margin the same width as the floated img, and you should be good to go.

Comment: The advice to move the `img` before the `<span>` was exactly what I needed!